# How to properly run ALTER VIEW after ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Lets say I have this SQL statements:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[tbl] ALTER COLUMN col1 varchar(300)
ALTER TABLE dbo.[tbl] ALTER COLUMN col2 varchar(20)
ALTER TABLE dbo.[tbl] ALTER COLUMN col3 varchar(20)
ALTER TABLE dbo.[tbl] ALTER COLUMN col4 varchar(100)
```

I have put these statements inside a file to be run one after the other.  I also have a VIEW that is looking at dbo.[tbl]. I noticed that after running the 4 statements above the VIEW retains the old column lengths.  So I added the following code to the end of the file:

```
ALTER  VIEW [dbo].[tbl]
AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM   dbo.[tbl]
```

The error that I get is

```
'ALTER VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
```

So my question is, what is the best way to ensure that my VIEW retains the new column lengths?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For this specific purpose, use [`sp_refreshview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx).

```
exec sp_refreshview N'dbo.tbl'
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `GO` statements:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[tbl] ALTER COLUMN col1 varchar(300)
ALTER TABLE dbo.[tbl] ALTER COLUMN col2 varchar(20)
ALTER TABLE dbo.[tbl] ALTER COLUMN col3 varchar(20)
ALTER TABLE dbo.[tbl] ALTER COLUMN col4 varchar(100)
GO

ALTER  VIEW [dbo].[tbl]
AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM   dbo.[tbl]
GO
```

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I didnt think it was important to add but I put PRINT statements in there also.  Apparently, the ALTER VIEW wont work if there are any PRINT statements before it.  But otherwise, this work.  Thanks Holistic Developer.

Comment: This only works in SSMS and related tools - `GO` is not a Transact SQL keyword.